# What common item am I

Tags: riddle, word

My appearance is about as varied as it could be
Unless you unveil me, you won't see the real me
Without me, you life can become a pain after the act
but by having one of me,
happiness can be extended which can be a fact
My lifetime is short
but your experience I shall support.

What am I?

Comment: @randal'thor OP's prev riddle says intangible which I really wish my answer were! But I see that fits the theme `:o)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You're a condom, Sir! Please keep supporting my experiences.
>  Explanation: Well the appearance can really vary as it takes the form of just about anything that fills it. You have to unveil it to see it for real, otherwise it's just an ordinary rubber. Life does become a pain after `the act` unless you had one on! Happiness could as well be derived from pleasure which especially the ribbed ones extend for me. Its lifetime is short, well as short as a couple of seconds for certain. It does always support the experience before it dies in the trash.

Well usually I stick to posting comments when I'm inebriated but a fellow SE'er motivated me to do it this time.

Comment: Umm, why condom? Please explain

Comment: @Python is right - I suggested you post an answer, not an unexplained answer! ;-) I've already upvoted though.

Comment: @PythonMaster here you go, Sir! Thanks Mr. Al'thor!

Answer (score 3):

How about a

> bandaid

My appearance is about as varied as it could be

> bandaids have all kinds of printed patterns and some variation in shape

Unless you unveil me, you won't see the real me

> bandaids' real use is in covering wounds. The adhesive side has to be unveiled in order to be used

Without me, you life can become a pain after the act but by having one of me,
happiness can be extended which can be a fact

> bandaids help by covering painful areas, decreasing the time someone might spend feeling hurt from a cut

My lifetime is short
but your experience I shall support.

> bandaids don't last very long, no more than a day

Answer (score 0):

What about (and apologies in advance).

> A poo!

My appearance is about as varied as it could be

> Everyone's poo looks different, and can be different all the time

Unless you unveil me, you won't see the real me

> You know its there, but until you have 'unveiled' it, you cannot see what it looks like.

Without me, you life can become a pain after the act but by having one of me, happiness can be extended which can be a fact

> Who hasn't felt happiness after doing a poo. Can be quite relieving sometimes. And if you don't do it, then yes you can be in pain.

My lifetime is short but your experience I shall support.

> yep once you flush him, he is gone! And of course, your experiencing in getting it out, is wholly supported by said poo.